# Get-AzureRmStorageAccount, Dig into Container files and get "Modified" property

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to get all Storage Accounts which last modified date is 6 months ago with PS script.
I didn't found any cmdlet or function which could provide such information. I thought it would be enough to sort by 'LastModifiedTime' but then I dig dipper, I saw that I have a lot of new files inside containers with the parameter "Modified". Question is how can I access these files with Powershell? Any cmdlet, function, etc?

Here is what I used to get SA before:

```
    function check_stores {

$stores = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'"
$x = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

foreach($store in $stores){

$storename = $store.Name

$dates = (Get-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $store.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $store.Name).LastModifiedTime

    if(!($dates -ge $x)){

        "Storage Account Name: $storename"

    }}
    }
    check_stores
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you just want to get the blobs which LastModifiedTime (aka: LMT) is in 180 days.
If so, you don't need to check the container LMT, since it is not related with blob last modify time. (container LMT is for container properties modification).

Following script works with pipeline. If you don't need to check container LMT, just remove the check:

```
$x = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

# get all storage accounts of current subscription
$accounts = Get-AzStorageAccount

foreach($a in $accounts)
{
  # get container of storage account with LMT in 180 days
  $containers =   $a | Get-AzStorageContainer | ? {$_.LastModified -ge $x}
  # if don't need check container LMT, use : $containers =   $a[0] | Get-AzStorageContainer

  # get blob of containers with LMT in 180 days
  $blobs =  $containers | Get-AzStorageBlob | ? {$_.LastModified -ge $x}

  #add code to handle blobs
  echo $blobs
}
```